# Реализация своего загрузчика классов

Tags: java

В каких реальных ситуациях может пригодиться наличие своего (самописного) `ClassLoader`'a? Я уже давно пишу на Java, но этого никогда не требовалось. Приходилось ли вам в реальном проекте реализовывать загрузчик классов самостоятельно?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть ещё вариант: предоставление возможности динамически обновлять какие-то часто изменяемые компоненты без рестарта. Может быть полезно, если стоимость простоя системы высока и тогда остановка виртуальной машины для доставки новых версий недопустима. В таком случае, удобно подгружать новые версии компонентов на ходу.

**UPD**

Вот пример из жизни. Есть некая система обработки данных. И есть правила обработки данных, которые поставляются отдельно в виде Groovy-скриптов. Надо уметь по команде скачивать эти скрипты определённой версии и на ходу подцеплять. Сама engine остаётся всё тот же, данные всё те же, но бизнес-логика часто меняется, а стопать нагруженную систему на каждом чихе нежелательно.

Answer (score 2):

Свой загрузчик имеют, например, приложения, которые управляют жизненным циклом других приложенияй - например, сервера приложений. Так что если вы его пишите - понадобится. Частным случаем может быть система плагинов/аддонов для вашей аппликухи.

А где еще может? Первая идея - дистрибьюция приложений с зашифрованными классами - для обеспечения сохранности алгоритмов или там для поддержки лицензии.

Самому мне не приходилось такое делать (опыт, впрочем, небольшой). Будет интересно послушать другие (реальные?) варианты.